# Retrieving $_.Extension with double file extensions

Tags: powershell, filenames

It seems like Powershell's `.Extension` method doesn't recognize double extensions.
As a result, something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path:. | Rename-Item -NewName {
  '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '\.', '_'), $_.Extension
}
```

ends up renaming `file.1.tar.gz` to `file_1_tar.gz`, while I want `file_1.tar.gz`.

Just an oversight?
Or can it be mitigated?

Comment: Because double extensions do not exist. Otherwise, what would be the extension of `My.cool.document.pdf`, `document.pdf.pdf.pdf` or `file.zip.tar.gz`? ;-) Be aware that even single extensions are just part of the filename. You can rename `file.1.tar.gz` to `foo` and will still be able to unzip and untar it. Your OS might just not offer you that option automagically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

Here's a quote from Microsoft Doc. regarding the `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension` method, which seems to share the same implementation logic with other similar functions and Powershell Cmdlets.

> This method obtains the extension of path by searching path for a
> period (.), starting with the last character in path and continuing
> toward the first character. If a period is found before a
> DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar character, the
> returned string contains the period and the characters after it;
> otherwise, String.Empty is returned.

You can of course mitigate this by either creating an exception for tar.gz and other  double extension by using a dictionary to define what should be treated as double exception. Here is an example of mitigation.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' | % {
    $BaseName = $_.BaseName
    $Extension = $_.Extension
    if ($_.FullName.EndsWith('.tar.gz')) {
        $BaseName = $_.BaseName.SubString(0,$_.BaseName.Length -4)
        # I used the full name as reference to preserve the case on the filenames
        $Extension = $_.FullName.Substring($_.FullName.Length - 7)
    }

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName (
        '{0}{1}' -f ($BaseName -replace '.', '_'), $Extension
    )

}
```

Note that since I had only `.tar.gz`, I did not actually use a dictionary but should you have multiple double extension type, the best way would be to apply this method through a loop against each extension to see if it match.

Take this, for instance, which loop through an array to check against multiple double extensions

```
# Outside of the main loop to avoid redeclaring each time.
$DoubleExtensionDict = @('.tar.gz', '.abc.def')

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' | % {
    $BaseName = $_.BaseName
    $Extension = $_.Extension

    Foreach ($ext in $DoubleExtensionDict) {
        if ($_.FullName.EndsWith($ext)) {
            $FirstExtLength = ($ext.split('.')[1]).Length 
            $BaseName = $_.BaseName.SubString(0, $_.BaseName.Length - $FirstExtLength -1)
            $Extension = $_.FullName.Substring($_.FullName.Length - 7)
            break
        }
    }
    
     Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName (
         '{0}{1}' -f ($BaseName -replace '.', '_'), $Extension
     )

}
```

**References**

[Path.GetExtension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 2):

As [Sage Pourpre's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70371344/45375) notes, by design only the *last* `.`-separated token is considered the filename extension.

Short of creating a hashtable (dictionary) of known "multi-extensions", as Sage proposes - which would have to anticipate *all* of them - **you can try a *heuristic*** based on the following rules (since you need to rule out considering `.1` part of the multi-extension):

- Any nonempty run of `.`-separated tokens *that do not start with a digit*, at the *end* of a file name, is considered the multi-extension, including the `.` chars:

```
@{ Name = 'file.1.tar.gz'},
@{ Name = 'file.1.tar.zip'},
@{ Name = 'file.1.html'},
@{ Name = 'file.1.ps1'},
@{ Name = 'other.1'} | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -match '(.+?)((?:\.[^\d]+))$') {
      $basename = $Matches[1]
      $exts = $Matches[2]
    } else {
      $basename = $_.Name
      $exts = ''
    }
    ($basename -replace '\.', '_') + $exts
  }
```

The above yields:

```
file_1.tar.gz
file_1.tar.zip
file_1.html
file_1.ps1
other_1
```